# How to read decimal numbers from a specific column in a csv file convert them to HH.MM and total up the number of hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, converters

I am trying to create a program to read the first and sixth row which has decimal numbers in a csv file and then convert those numbers to HH.MM. Then total up the amount of hours and output them.

Here is my code so far

```
import csv

with open("tracking_original2.csv") as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  rows = csv.reader(f)
  for row in rows:
    print(row[1],' ',row[6])

This outputs:
Customer   1
Customer   0.5
Customer   0.93
Customer   1.2
Customer   0.73
Customer   0.5
Customer   0.54
Customer   0.13
Customer   0.56
Customer   0.99
```

I am completely lost on how to proceed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sum your hours up,  multiply them by 60 to get minutes. Then you extract full hours and leftover minutes:

```
minutes = sum( [ 1 , 0.5 , 0.93 , 1.2 , 0.73 , 0.5 , 0.54 , 0.13 , 0.56 , 0.99 ]) * 60 
print( f'{int(minutes//60):02d}:{int(minutes)%60:02d}')
```

The printing uses formatting to get 00:00 format: see [format mini languague](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatspec) and [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

I am using integer floored division `//` to get the full integer part and modulo `%` to get the remainder minutes. I discard any fractional parts by converting the result to `int()`
Output:

```
07:04
```

You could also get fancy and wrapp this into a function:

```
def asHourString(decimalPlacesHours):
    """Converts decimal workhours into HH:MM format. 

    Works with int,float and list of float-convertables, else
    throws ValueError"""

    minutes = 0.0
    if isinstance(decimalPlacesHours,float) or isinstance(decimalPlacesHours,int) :
        minutes = decimalPlacesHours * 60
    elif isinstance(decimalPlacesHours,list) and decimalPlacesHours:
        try:
            minutes = sum(map(float,decimalPlacesHours))
        except (ValueError,IndexError):
            raise ValueError("Supply float or list convertable to float")
    else:   
        raise ValueError("Supply float or list convertable to float") 

    return f'{int(minutes//60):02d}:{int(minutes)%60:02d}'   

print(asHourString(21.49))
print(asHourString([21.49,2.12]))
print(asHourString(["21.49","2.12"])) 
print(asHourString(-5))
# print(asHourString("does not work")) # ValueError
```

Output:

```
21:29
00:23
00:23
-5:00
```